# Tool/trick to replace tabs in all files of an entire VS solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My solution (30+ project) is a bit of a mess when it comes to mixing tabs and spaces, and I want to fix this with one easy step.

Does anybody know a trick/tool to do this in one step for the entire solution?

EDIT: Not exactly what I meant. I want the documents to be nicely formatted. Just find/replace wont do.. documents will still be a mess. 
I want something like the Format -> Advanced -> Format Document command

Comment: a quick script would do. If you can run IronPython, IronRuby or Boo it would be super easy. doing this is C# is also not-too-complex. I could attach as script as an answer if you like

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In case if your files contains spaces as tabs of equal width all along the solution (i.e. 4 spaces per tab), then you should use plain VS's `Quick replace` tool. In order to follow `StyleCop`'s formatting rules, you should use spaces instead of tabs, so go to `Quick replace` (CTRL-h), select `Use wildcard` and then in `Find what` field you can use `\t` symbol, replacing it with 4 spaces for all solution (`Look in` field).

**But** if your solution files contains tabs made of spaces of different width, or you want to apply **single-style formatting**, then you definitely should use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)'s feature to reformat code. This feature is called [Code Cleanup](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html). To apply `code cleanup` to whole solution or selected project, go to the solution explorer and select `Cleanup code` in context menu. But before launching reformatting on whole solution try and tweak it on one file, there's a lot of options in Resharper's settings.

Answer (score 5):

there you go:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class _Runner {
  static void Main(string[] args) {

    var root=args[0];
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    int updated = 0;
    foreach (var path in filePaths) {
      var content = File.ReadAllText(path);
      var replaced = content.Replace("    ", "\t");
      if (replaced == content) { 
        continue;
      }

      ++updated;
      Console.WriteLine("fixing " + path);
      File.WriteAllText(path, replaced);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("fixed {0} files", updated);  
  }
}
```

Save is as `spaces-to-tabs.cs`, and run:

```
C:>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc spaces-to-tab.cs
C:>spaces-to-tabs.exe C:\path\to\your\solution
```

Comment: Note of warning: this will replace four spaces regardless of where that occurs, i.e. inside literal strings where tab may not be desirable.

Answer (score 3):

I keep a unix tool directory in my path when working in Windows, for just such emergencies. For instance, this would replace all tabs with 4 spaces, in any .cs files in the c:\myproject directory or it's subdirectories.

```
find c:\myproject -name *.cs -exec sed -i -e "\"s/\t/    /g\"" {} ";"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple and fast way is to open file in notepad++ and either replace it manually (switch on 'show all characters' and tabs will be highlighted), or replace it automatically (have to play with a 'Settings')

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but the extension "Fix Mixed Tabs" is a huge help
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.FixMixedTabs

Basically when you open a file that has mixed tabs/spaces whitespace, it popup up a toolbar at the top of the file to allow you to normalize it

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-h, set "Look in:" to "entire solution"

Also you can record a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I use my trusty code cleanup tool CodeMaid: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid

If you run cleanup solution it will take a while but it does remove unused usings and re-order usings.  It will also provide consistent spacing throughout the solution.

The only issue is that you need to have Windows to run Visual Studio for this extension.